# A Semiring without distributive property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semiring

Is there a precedent for a structure that has two monoids where the additive identity also absorbs with multiplication, but multiplication does not distribute over addition.
So it's basically a Semiring except for distributivity. It's close to a Near Ring, but not quite. Is there a name for such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

What you said, plus distributivity on a side, is called a [near-semiring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-semiring).

I doubt the version with no distributivity at all has been named or interested anyone: it is far too loose a coupling between the operations.  Without such a condition, there is no interplay between the operations.

Comment: I think distributivity is mandatory and the strongest axiom for a semiring.